# DAM assets are not getting cached in dispatcher adobe aem

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I am activating the content(pages and images) from cq author, the activated content(pages and images) is available in the publisher.
When running the same pages the content(pages) is coming properly but the images are not getting cached. The dispatcher is trying to create the cache for the images but after that it doesn't cache anything.
The content and etc folders are getting cached but not content/dam.
Here is my cache rule in the dispacher.any file

```
/rules
                {
                /0000
                  {
                  # the globbing pattern to be compared against the url
                  # example: *             -> everything
                  #        : /foo/bar.*    -> only the /foo/bar documents
                  #        : /foo/bar/*    -> all pages below /foo/bar
                  #        : /foo/bar[./]* -> all pages below and /foo/bar itself
                  #        : *.html        -> all .html files
                  /glob "*"
                  /type "allow"
                  }
                }
```

Please provide your valuable support to fix this issue.
thanks

Comment: Are you able to access same asset on publish (without login)? Check if your assets require some kind of authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set the following directive in your apache configuration if you have mod_dir and mod_mime enabled:

```
ModMimeUsePathInfo On
DirectorySlash Off
```

For more information please have a look at: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-tshoot.html